# Couple all keys that have the same values:

Tags: javascript, arrays, key

I have a key-value array that stores nodes and all their connections. The array looks something like:

```
A => {C}
B => {D}
C => {A,F,G,H,J}
D => {B}
E => {F,G,H}
F => {C,E}
G => {C,E}
H => {C,E}
I => {-}
J => {C}
K => {-}
```

I would like to couple all the keys that have the same values. In this case F,G and H have the same values, as well as A and J. I would like to put them in an array something like arr = [{F,G,H},{A,J}];

How can that be done in javascript?

Comment: Are the values on the left hand sides (A,B,C....) all different arrays?

Comment: Yes, i`m sorry if the curly brackets are confusing, I will edit them now.

Comment: Can you please use actual Javascript syntax when showing your data structure.  I really have no idea what your current syntax means.  In addition, Javascript does not have key/value arrays so that leaves me confused too. And, something like `{A,F,G,H,J}` does not tell us what that really is, nor does `A => {C}`.

Comment: Also, I assume, the values in the curly braces are actually objects that have a property (like ID or something) that is your key that you want to group by?

Answer (score 0):

in order to solve this you need to have a deeper information of how javascript work

look at this code

```
var a = []
var b = [a]
a.push(b)
```

if you look at the variable of `b` you will see that its an empty array. the reason of that is the when you try to assign `a = [b]` javascript will erase your value in b because its a circular dependency.

in order to solve it you need to define the `a` and `b` in anther way.

look at this code

```
var c,d;
Object.defineProperty(window,'c',{value : []});
Object.defineProperty(window,'d',{value : []});
c.push(d);
```

now if you look at `c` its have a circular dependency;

for more information about [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question